# How to run a RCP Maven/Tycho Application

Tags: java, maven, rcp, tycho

In order to run my application on a CI Server (jenkins) I am trying to create a headless build.

In order to do so, I am following the Eclipse Con Tutorial with some minor changes (using Indigo instead of Eclipse 4) which can be found here: https://github.com/jsievers/tycho-demo/tree/master/exercises

I was able to to finish part one (wasn't really hard, mvn clean install) but now i ended up with a target folder and a jar file named like my project: mail-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar but I am quite confused since I am not able to run it.

I have tried `java -jar mail-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, which produces the following failure:

> no main manifest attribute, in mail-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

In the tutorial there is no further advice so I am not sure what the purpose of this step is.

Answer (score 3):

It seems, that file you are trying to run is simply an OSGi bundle.

The final artifact of RCP application build should be a ZIP file, not just a JAR. If you work with tycho-demo, try to look at **tychodemo.product** subproject. After mvn clean install you will find some ZIP files like **tychodemo.product-linux.gtk.x86_64.zip** in its **target/products** folder. Executable files are packaged in them with all necessary dependencies (i.e. platform-dependent).

To include your bundle to your Tycho RCP product just add it to pom.xml like it is done with **tychodemo.bundle**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which portion of that demonstration code you are working with, but I'm pretty sure that the only part of it that will give you a working RCP app after running 'mvn clean install' will be the one called "Exercise_05_Solution"

From there, you have to navigate to the pom.xml file that resides in tychodemo.parent, and then run 'mvn clean install' on that pom.xml file.

The build output that is the Eclipse RCP applications will be located at

```
.../tychodemo.repository/target/products/*.zip
```

These zip files work just like Eclipse does... just unzip them anywhere on your file system and launch the application using the executable inside.

I haven't tried this with this particular example, but my project I'm working on at my job follows the pattern that this demo uses almost exactly.

Good luck!